# Using PIL or a Numpy array, how can I remove entire rows from an image?

Tags: python, image-manipulation, python-imaging-library

I would like to know how I could remove entire rows from an image, preferably based on the color of the row?

Example:  I have an image that is 5 pixels in height, the top two rows and the bottom two rows are white and the middle row is black. I would like to know how I could get PIL to identify this row of black pixels, then,  remove the entire row and save the new image.

I have some knowledge of python and have so far been editing my images by listing the result of "getdata" so any answers with pseudo code may hopefully be enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote you the following code that removes every row which is completely black. I use the [else clause](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) of the `for` loop that will be executed when the loop is *not* exited by a break.

```
from PIL import Image

def find_rows_with_color(pixels, width, height, color):
    rows_found=[]
    for y in xrange(height):
        for x in xrange(width):
            if pixels[x, y] != color:
                break
        else:
            rows_found.append(y)
    return rows_found

old_im = Image.open("path/to/old/image.png")
if old_im.mode != 'RGB':
    old_im = old_im.convert('RGB')
pixels = old_im.load()
width, height = old_im.size[0], old_im.size[1]
rows_to_remove = find_rows_with_color(pixels, width, height, (0, 0, 0)) #Remove black rows
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (width, height - len(rows_to_remove)))
pixels_new = new_im.load()
rows_removed = 0
for y in xrange(old_im.size[1]):
    if y not in rows_to_remove:
        for x in xrange(new_im.size[0]):
            pixels_new[x, y - rows_removed] = pixels[x, y]
    else:
        rows_removed += 1
new_im.save("path/to/new/image.png")
```

If you have questions just ask :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer halex. I think I should have been a bit more specific with the example I gave, as I tried something similar before. It's possible that any of the rows may start with a black pixel, so some rows that are not meant to be removed,  are. That's why I needed to know how to remove only rows that are entirely black (color not important, just given as example) or even rows that are entirely transparent.

Comment: @Py-Newbie I changed the code to remove rows that are completely black. If you want to remove rows that are transparent you must not convert the image to RGB but to `RGBA`.

Comment: Thanks again for help with that it worked perfectly. I have another question for you, is it possible to modify the code you wrote to find all-black columns (not rows as before), crop what's in between the columns and make new images out of them. An example image can be found here http://postimage.org/image/bh8or7yzn. From that sample the objective is to have 10 separate images. I hope this is enough detail for you to understand what I mean.

Comment: It works very good for rows but how to perform it for the columns.